# Can i run spring boot application without snakeyaml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, snakeyaml

I excluded snakeyaml due to vulnerability.
Now it won't recognize application.properties and my app wont start in my Intellij IDE or even via command line through `gradle bootRun`.

Is snakeyaml specifially used to reading yaml files, or it is required to load application.properties as well ??

EDIT 1: I excluded all snakeyaml dependencies from `build.gradle` as:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.yaml', module: 'snakeyaml'
}
```

Build fails at test cases level as:

```
> Task :test

RestApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:47
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:47
```

When i run the application i get the below error :

```
> Task :app:bootRun FAILED
18:52:47.125 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to load Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' but snakeyaml was not found on the classpath
        at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:47)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:36)
```

Comment: If you aren't using YAML you aren't at risk and can just leave the dependency.

Comment: I think snakeyaml is tied to spring framework. When i exclude i get the above errors..

Comment: Where did I state you should exclude it? You can leave it in if you aren't using Yaml. You are only at risk if you are loading Yaml.

Comment: So actually snakeyaml has been blocked by my org due to vulnerability and it is failing my build

Comment: a great panick because something is in and not used, add global ban. Instead of investigating and take proper care. Well Spring Boot doesn't run without it so you need it to run, but as stated you aren't at risk if you aren't reading YAML.

Comment: The arguments that you're not at risk if you're not using it are all spurious and should be ignored. It's complete nonsense and only a real novice with absolutely no knowledge of security would say something so wrong. Ignore them.

Comment: @Deinum i am not using it to read yaml. I have replaced my application.yml with application.properties

Comment: The failure has occurred because you still have an `application.yml` file on the classpath. If you delete that file, SnakeYAML will no longer be required and your app should start without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to ask the authors of the lib to fix the vulnerability. Failing that, try to fix it yourself, build the lib and upload it to your org's repo and depend on that instead. Your error isn't due to the missing lib as such, it's due to the missing classes, so you can provide your own if you want that don't do anything (assuming they're not really used), or implement the interface yourself if it is actually used.

The arguments that you're not at risk if you're not using it are all spurious and should be ignored. It's complete nonsense and only a real novice with absolutely no knowledge of security would say something so wrong. Ignore them. You should not load vulnerable libs in your app because a malicious user could, potentially, execute code in your app that does use the vulnerable lib.

Comment: Is it possible to replace snakeyaml with jackson dataformat yaml in the artifacts of the spring dependency tree?

Comment: I don't think this line of reasoning makes sense, at least not on the JVM. There are many APIs in the JDK itself that can produce a security vulnerability if used incorrectly. For example, if you pass untrusted input into `ObjectInputStream` and call `readObject()` you are vulnerable to remote code execution. `ObjectInputStream` is part of the `java.base` module so you have no choice but for it to be available in an app running on the JVM.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - where is the reasoning nonsensical? I'm completely lost by your argument. My reasoning: don't increase your attack surface if you don't have to, and don't use libs with known (>major) vulns. Your argument starts by saying this is nonsense and you continue to say that the JVM contains methods that can be used in an attack, therefore we don't need to worry. I'm lost, can you explain, please?

Comment: @user1354825 No, I don't think so. You have to provide a class with the given name and path.

Comment: I didn't say there was no need to worry. My argument is that deciding whether or not to include a dependency purely depending on whether or not it is potentially vulnerable does not make sense. After all, the JDK itself contains code that, when misused or exposed to untrusted input, is vulnerable. In the context of this question, you can use SnakeYAML with no increase to your application's attack surface. Just like the JDK's `ObjectInputStream`, SnakeYAML is only a problem if you pass it untrusted input and there's no reason not to use it if you take the appropriate care.

Comment: No, that's not the case. In this case there is a known and reported vulnerability against the library. Imagine I asked you to point a revolver (gun) at your head, but it wasn't loaded. I guess you'd check it and see that it wasn't loaded and then point it at your head, safe in the knowledge that nothing could go wrong. Now, same thought experiment, but with a gun with 1 bullet in it. You're not going to pull the trigger, that would be sick. But, are you telling me there's no more risk now that you know that there's a bullet there? This situation is the same -- there's a bullet in the gun.